# Understanding how `gdalwarp` works under the hood

Tags: gdal, c++, gdalwarp

I try to understand how `gdalwarp` works.
[Here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html) is a reference to `Affine GeoTransform`, but I can't understand the terminology

1. pixel/line is it x,y coordinates of image?
2. does pixel width and height mean scaling of image?

Is `gdalwarp` just do affine transform as for example OpenCV's [warpAffine](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine)?

But if we assume if it do usual affine tranform, how it work with such low values in affine matrix (it should just shrink image).
For example:

```
<GeoTransform>31.8262087982, -7.53176140574e-07, 3.42507371786e-06, 59.2404952064, 1.75338700993e-06, 3.86201833742e-07</GeoTransform>
```

Also I tried to find code part that related to warping but it's not very easy to read.

[Here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/dac763d03dbe3445cac9ac4d43a41d04bc161a7b/gdal/apps/gdalwarp_bin.cpp) is main `gdalwarp` binary code. As I understand last function where transform performed is [GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/60d2e1a2768f5a4ad02df5587b8aea3f9afa4241/gdal/alg/gdaltransformer.cpp#L925), but I'm not understand how `GeoTransform` used in this transform.

In [this document](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/gdal/workshop/foss4ge2015/workshop_gdal.pdf)

```
The GeoTransform is the geo-transformation matrix, which is in mathematics described as an affine
transformation from the coordinates in the pixel space (col,row) to the coordinates of the projected
space (X,Y), with col and row starting from 0 for the upper-left pixel (in pixel space, not necessarily
in projected space!)
```

Not sure what is meant by `projected space`.

Answer (score 4):

GeoTransform is an array that contains six numbers:

1. X origin
2. Pixel width
3. Angle (with vertical axis)
4. Y origin
5. Pixel height
6. Angle (with horizontal axis)

X and Y are coordinates of the top left corner of your raster image.
Each pixel has size, width and height and it is a value in meters or degrees (depends on your CRS) - this value is constant, not scalable, ex. one pixel on your map can depict 100 square meters of area and its size is 10x10m (WxH). Angle is simply an angle between a particular axis from the coordinates reference system and axis of your image.

This information is enough to perform all operations. If you want to calculate which pixel has X,Y coordinates, just calculate:

> (Xcoordinate - Xorigin) / PixelWidth

You don't need more information. You can resample this image, GeoTransform values will be changed, but after that to do something with raster you will use only this 6 numbers.

Comment: What is CRS? And what kind of transform `gdalwarp` perform (is it affine or not)? And what is `georeferenced coordinates` is it GPS coordinates?

Comment: CRS is coordinates reference system (ex. UTM). Georeferenced coordinates are simply coordinates (x,y) of any point on your map. Affine transformation will be performed if you do the reprojection or resampling, there is no need to do transformation to get these 6 values, or get the value of NxM pixel.

Comment: GDAL can utilize either Affine GeoTransform or ground control points http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html. The main use of gdalwarp is to transform images from one coordinate system into another which is much more than just affine transformation.

Comment: Although not specific to gdal you should look at this online book it has descriptions of affine transforms, and how they relate the raster projections and warping https://mmann1123.github.io/pyGIS/docs/d_raster_crs_intro.html